# Null Pointer Dereference in switchEffectRawNative with Flutter Plugin for Android and DeepAR

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I am using DeepAR (https://developer.deepar.ai/) in conjunction with Flutter. I am creating a Flutter plugin for Android. I use the JetPack support library CameraX for camera access. The library provides a use case called "ImageAnalyse" (https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze). I try to combine this with DeepAR. The masks that I want to display with DeepAR via the camera are in the App Bundle as assets. When I call "switchEffect", the app crashes.

**The Flutter Plugin**

The architecture of the Flutter Plugin follows the recommendations in the Flutter documentation.

```
class ExamplePlugin : FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware {
    private var flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPluginBinding? = null
    private var activityPluginBinding: ActivityPluginBinding? = null
    // overrides are implemented but left out for simplicity
}
```

```
class PluginViewFactory(
    private val flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding, private val activityPluginBinding: ActivityPluginBinding
) : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {

    override fun create(context: Context?, id: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {
        return PluginView(flutterPluginBinding, activityPluginBinding, context, id, args)
    }
}
```

```
class PluginView(
    flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPluginBinding,
    activityPluginBinding: ActivityPluginBinding,
    private val context: Context?,
    id: Int,
    args: Any?
) : PlatformView, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler, PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener,
    AREventListener {
    private val activity = activityPluginBinding.activity
    // I left out some code for simplicity
```

**Creating the ProcessCameraProvider**

```
    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(activity)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindPreviewAndAnalysis(cameraProvider)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity))
    }
```

**Bind image preview and image analysis use cases**

```
    private fun bindPreviewAndAnalysis(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider?) {
        // Preview
        val imagePreview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }

        // Analysis
        val cameraPreset = CameraResolutionPreset.P1280x720
        val width: Int
        val height: Int
        val orientation: Int = getScreenOrientation()
        if (orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE || orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            width = cameraPreset.width
            height = cameraPreset.height
        } else {
            width = cameraPreset.height
            height = cameraPreset.width
        }
        arrayOfNulls<ByteBuffer>(NUMBER_OF_BUFFERS).also { buffers = it }
        for (i in 0 until NUMBER_OF_BUFFERS) {
            buffers[i] = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 3)
            buffers[i]?.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            buffers[i]?.position(0)
        }
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetResolution(Size(width, height))
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build()
        cameraExecutor?.let {
            imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                it,
                { image ->
                    val byteData: ByteArray
                    val yBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                    val uBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer
                    val vBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer
                    val ySize: Int = yBuffer.remaining()
                    val uSize: Int = uBuffer.remaining()
                    val vSize: Int = vBuffer.remaining()
                    byteData = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)

                    //U and V are swapped
                    yBuffer.get(byteData, 0, ySize)
                    vBuffer.get(byteData, ySize, vSize)
                    uBuffer.get(byteData, ySize + vSize, uSize)
                    buffers[currentBuffer]?.put(byteData)
                    buffers[currentBuffer]?.position(0)
                    if (deepAR != null) {
                        deepAR?.receiveFrame(
                            buffers[currentBuffer],
                            image.width,
                            image.height,
                            image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees,
                            cameraSelector == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA,
                            DeepARImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
                            image.planes[1].pixelStride
                        )
                    }
                    currentBuffer = (currentBuffer + 1) % NUMBER_OF_BUFFERS
                    image.close()
                })
        }

        try {
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

            cameraSelector?.let {
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(activity as LifecycleOwner,
                    it, imagePreview, imageAnalysis)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", e)
        }
    }
```

**use DeepAR switchEffect**

```
    private fun changeMask(mask: String) {
        try {
            val loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
            val path = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset("assets/masks/$mask", "my_plugin_name")
            val maskFd: AssetFileDescriptor = activity.assets.openFd(path)
            deepAR?.switchEffect("masks", maskFd.createInputStream())
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not change mask", exc)
        }
    }
```

**Error**

When the "switchEffect" is called, the app crashes with the following error:

```
F/libc    (20852): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 20852 (.example.app), pid 20852 (.example.app)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/walleye/walleye:11/RP1A.201005.004.A1/6934943:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-07-25 13:59:29+0200
pid: 20852, tid: 20852, name: .example.app  >>> com.example.app <<<
uid: 10194
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000007129de3570  x1  0000007129de3570  x2  0000007139e3b210  x3  0000007119769984
    x4  0000007ff61c6788  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000001  x7  6ced3fea237c8a73
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  6ced3fea237c8a73  x10 0000000000430000  x11 0000000029de3576
    x12 000000005375645e  x13 0000007ff61c68a0  x14 0000000000000002  x15 00000000ebad6a89
    x16 00000073acaaa7f8  x17 00000073aabc5bd0  x18 00000073af972000  x19 0000007139e3b210
    x20 0000007ff61c68b0  x21 00000071d9d95c70  x22 0000000000000001  x23 0000007ff61c68b4
    x24 0000000000000000  x25 00000073af273000  x26 0000000000000069  x27 0000007119d77000
    x28 0000007ff61c68c0  x29 0000007ff61c6890
    lr  000000707f88e504  sp  0000007ff61c6850  pc  000000707f88e514  pst 0000000060000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000004a514  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libnative-lib.so (Java_ai_deepar_ar_DeepAR_switchEffectRawNative+268) (BuildId: 342abf6bf48a1e62b230a5496cbaeecab0b6c701)
      #01 pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #02 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #03 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #04 pc 000000000031c040  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #05 pc 0000000000313288  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #06 pc 000000000068b144  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+436) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #07 pc 000000000012dc14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct_range+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #08 pc 0000000000162a36  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk] (ai.deepar.ar.DeepAR.switchEffect+70)
      #09 pc 0000000000685960  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #10 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #11 pc 000000000001a49c  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes2.dex] (com.example.plugin.PluginView.changeMask+296)
      #12 pc 0000000000687fe8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #13 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #14 pc 000000000001a53a  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes2.dex] (com.example.plugin.PluginView.changeMaskNative+42)
      #15 pc 0000000000687fe8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #16 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #17 pc 000000000001a962  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes2.dex] (com.example.plugin.PluginView.onMethodCall+154)
      #18 pc 00000000006873a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1812) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #19 pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #20 pc 000000000036ef32  [anon:dalvik-classes6.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes6.dex] (io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage+34)
      #21 pc 00000000006873a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1812) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #22 pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #23 pc 0000000000364daa  [anon:dalvik-classes6.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes6.dex] (io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart+114)
      #24 pc 00000000006873a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1812) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #25 pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #26 pc 0000000000363a64  [anon:dalvik-classes6.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/base.apk!classes6.dex] (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage+8)
      #27 pc 00000000003094d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7618685802058321727)+264) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #28 pc 00000000006740c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+776) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #29 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #30 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #31 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #32 pc 000000000055c6f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+468) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #33 pc 000000000055c894  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #34 pc 00000000004197f8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #35 pc 000000000037deac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2532) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #36 pc 000000000036bc50  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+72) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #37 pc 000000000132663c  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #38 pc 0000000001326578  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #39 pc 0000000001322408  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #40 pc 000000000138428c  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #41 pc 0000000001342568  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #42 pc 00000000013476f8  /data/app/~~tCz51U3rHjeb2hAFXQB6yw==/com.example.app-xzIovrW9JsSRapHSrOSbnA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 137d09ab83a412ded1c33ef386351fcc0429a53b)
      #43 pc 000000000001a064  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916) (BuildId: b81fad2b6b7b7f85c6217d2cb80c9e61)
      #44 pc 0000000000019c68  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: b81fad2b6b7b7f85c6217d2cb80c9e61)
      #45 pc 00000000001120f4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44) (BuildId: 30f3430e4d2a28be49d3c60d623f0a29)
      #46 pc 000000000020fadc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+140) (BuildId: da25c976c2d1d3af123868772655a0779f8f6a48)
      #47 pc 000000000200b6cc  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (offset 0x2000000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+204)
      #48 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #49 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #50 pc 000000000031c040  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #51 pc 0000000000312228  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+912) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #52 pc 00000000006856c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #53 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #54 pc 0000000000396970  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x92b000) (android.os.Looper.loop+156)
      #55 pc 00000000003094d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7618685802058321727)+264) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #56 pc 0000000000311840  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #57 pc 0000000000312b9c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #58 pc 0000000000178658  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+58656) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #59 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #60 pc 00000000001a1698  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
      #61 pc 00000000003095d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7618685802058321727)+528) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #62 pc 00000000006740c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+776) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #63 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #64 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #65 pc 00000000001a9804  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #66 pc 000000000055ce14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #67 pc 00000000004dba28  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+48) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #68 pc 00000000000896f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: 13577ce71153c228ecf0eb73fc39f45010d487f8)
      #69 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #70 pc 00000000001a97e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #71 pc 000000000031c040  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #72 pc 0000000000312228  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+912) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #73 pc 00000000006856c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #74 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #75 pc 000000000044930a  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x125d000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
      #76 pc 00000000003094d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7618685802058321727)+264) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #77 pc 00000000006740c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+776) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #78 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #79 pc 0000000000897668  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2280) (BuildId: da25c976c2d1d3af123868772655a0779f8f6a48)
      #80 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #81 pc 00000000001a9804  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #82 pc 000000000055b830  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #83 pc 000000000055bcf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #84 pc 000000000043ecbc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+652) (BuildId: d0f321775158ed00df284edfabf672b6)
      #85 pc 000000000009948c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 30f3430e4d2a28be49d3c60d623f0a29)
      #86 pc 00000000000a0a0c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+844) (BuildId: 30f3430e4d2a28be49d3c60d623f0a29)
      #87 pc 0000000000003570  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1320) (BuildId: d4686d3f8282764488eb9ca7cc518583)
      #88 pc 00000000000495b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: c78cdff5b820a550771130d6bde95081)
Lost connection to device.
```

**Environment**

- Kotlin 1.5.20
- Flutter 2.2.3
- DeepAR 2.4.1
- CameraX 1.1.0-alpha07 / 1.0.0-alpha27

**Additional notes**

I see this error when running a Flutter App with Flutter Plugin on an Android Emulator (API Level 30) and on a real Android Device (Pixel 2, Android 11). I see this error when running the Flutter App in Debug-Mode and in Release-Mode.

Any help or any suggestions are very welcome. I'm quit new to Flutter and Android-Development, so there is a good chance I may have missed some important aspects.

I also posted this question in the GitHub repo of DeepAR: https://github.com/DeepARSDK/quickstart-android-java/issues/30

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know, that I have chosen a different approach now. In the end I'm using "switchEffect" with a FileInputStream and that works well:

```kotlin
    private fun getMaskAsFileInputStream(mask: String): FileInputStream? {
        return try {
            val loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
            val path = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset("assets/masks/$mask", "my_plugin_name")
            val maskFd: AssetFileDescriptor = activity.assets.openFd(path)
            if (maskFd.length > 0) {
                maskFd.createInputStream()
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Mask asset at $path is empty")
                null
            }
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get mask as file input stream", exc)
            null
        }
    }

    private fun changeMask(mask: String) {
        try {
            deepAR?.switchEffect("masks", getMaskAsFileInputStream(mask))
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not change mask", exc)
        }
    }
```